# Configurable Product turn Out of Stock when all child product are out of stock

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

Hey guys i got a little dilema. I am running Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

When you create a configurable product you must set the stock "in stock" and then you add the other additional products with different stock.

When the additional products stock goes to 0 the main configurable product still is "in stock".

I want that when all the additional products stock goes to 0 then the main configurable product stock to turn into "out of stock".

I am using this custom code for "out of stock" products to appear always at the bottom page. And unless the configurable product dont receive the option "out of stock" it cant go to bottom page.

```
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('_inventory_table'=>$this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),"_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id",array('is_in_stock', 'manage_stock'));
$this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('on_top','(CASE WHEN (((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 1) AND (_inventory_table.is_in_stock = 1)) OR  ((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 0) AND (1 - _inventory_table.manage_stock + _inventory_table.is_in_stock >= 1))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',array());
$this->getSelect()->order('on_top DESC');
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this? i'm facing the same issue here

Comment: hey i don't really remember what i did with that ... but i have a fix noted in a document that is related to this out of stock products. I just posted the answer ... take a look.

Comment: Maybe helps: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/470/configurable-product-inventory-stock-availability-status-doesnt-change-when

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Add this code**

```
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                array('_inventory_table'=>$this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
                "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id",
                array('is_in_stock', 'manage_stock')
            );
            $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('on_top',
            '(CASE WHEN (((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 1) AND (_inventory_table.is_in_stock = 1)) OR  ((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 0) AND (1 - _inventory_table.manage_stock + _inventory_table.is_in_stock >= 1))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',
             array());
            $this->getSelect()->order('on_top DESC');
```

**before line:**

```
if ($attribute == 'price' && $storeId != 0) {
```

**in files:**

**app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Collection.php**
**or in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Collection.php if you have  Magento 1.7.0.0 +**

Comment: I'm receiving this error message:

**You cannot define a correlation name '_inventory_table' more than once**

Comment: Is a bad practice changing the core.

Comment: I tried above code but didn't change the stock status not even show any error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you have the correct Magento settings?

```
Inventory "Show Out Of Stock" = "No"
Configurable product Manage Stock = "No"
Simple product /Manage Stock = "Yes"
```

Comment: Even with these settings: wouldnt a config product where the child products all have QTY=0 and IN_STOCK=0 still show?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work for you but I think you can solve this from the template itself on the file "app/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml", the line of code that says:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
<? else : ?>
enter code here
<?php endif ?>
```

if you base it from the original file in the base template you may see this code starting from line 100 as you can see if all the options of the configurable product is empty it means that all products are already sold out causing it not to display the form fields necessary for adding it to the cart.

I hope this helps. :)